# What are the advantages for using Command Query Responsibility Segregation over Repository pattern in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, cqrs

Can someone give me a better way to understand the advantages of using command-query separation over global repository pattern?

Answer (score 3):

CQS and repository are quite different concepts.  You might think of CQRS with a specific query handlers implementation.

Anyway, all these are compatible. CQRS implies a 'command' model i.e a model which is very easy to update. The repository pattern is used to abstract persistence. CQS means you don't do a command and a query in the same function (note that the query isn't a sql query). Basically, a command changes something, while a query reads and returns a result.

With a read model, you can have a specific querying services (aka handlers) used to handle querying use cases. In this case, a 'real' repository doesn't help very much, because the query handler itself abstracts the persistence. But in spirit, a query handler is basically a repository method.

Personally, I'm using repositories only with the Command (write/business) model. They do very little: Add, Get, Save, Delete . For querying needs, I have a read model with query handlers.